# Divergence of Green function expansion at the origin?

Tags: electrostatics, potential, greens-functions

The expansion of Green's function in spherical coordinate is given in Eq. (3.125) in Jackson by

$$G\left(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{x}^{\prime}\right)=4 \pi \sum_{l=0}^{\infty} \sum_{m=-l}^{l} \frac{Y_{l m}^{*}\left(\theta^{\prime}, \phi^{\prime}\right) Y_{l m}(\theta, \phi)}{(2 l+1)\left[1-\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^{2 l+1}\right]}\left(r_{<}^{l}-\frac{a^{2 l+1}}{r_{<}^{l+1}}\right)\left(\frac{1}{r_{>}^{l+1}}-\frac{r_{>}^{l}}{b^{2 l+1}}\right),$$

where $r_<$ ($r_>$) is the lesser (greater) of $r$ and $r'$.

The electric potential can be found using Eq. (1.42)

$$\Phi(\mathbf{x})=\frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_{0}} \int_{V} \rho\left(\mathbf{x}^{\prime}\right) G\left(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{x}^{\prime}\right) d^{3} x^{\prime} +\frac{1}{4 \pi} \oint_{S} [...]$$

If we have a single charge and it is located at the origin, then, $r_< = r'$, and the term $\frac{a^{2l+1}}{r_<^{l+1}}$ in (3.125) diverges.

What am I missing? Expression (3.125) should allow us to compute the potential due to a charge at the origin without diverging.

Comment: Even if the Green‘s function diverges, the integral for the potential does not necessarily have to diverge. Have you checked this?

Comment: Good point, but I did and it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equation (3.125) is the Green function for a spherical shell bounded by $r=a$ and $r=b$, where it vanishes. If you want to place a charge at the origin, you should first set $a=0$, and the problem will disappear.